# java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range - whitespaces in String

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

I'm trying to update a table in a database through PreparedStatement in ServletClass. It raises java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1). I guess, the problem is car string consists of more words, so it contains whitespaces, but I don't know how exactly solve it. I tried to remove two apostrophe marks surrounding the second question mark in the prepared statement but it didn't help. After removing quotes, there is still the following error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery()

Here is an extract of code:

```java
private void updateCarAvailability(int value, String car) throws Exception {
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement prst = null;
    try {
        conn = ds.getConnection();
        String sql = "update cars set available=? where name='?'";
        prst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        prst.setInt(1, value);
        prst.setString(2, car);
        prst.executeQuery(sql);
    }
```

Comment: Remove the single-quotes around the second `?`. I.e `'?'` should just be `?`.

Comment: Don't change your question to something different that invalidates existing answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to remove the `'` on `where name='?'`, so it should look like `update cars set available=? where name=?`, and also you should change `executeQuery` for `execute`, once you're using an update command.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the single quotes around the `?`

```
String sql = "update cars set available=? where name=?";
```

They are not needed as the actual value is not passed as part of the SQL statement but as a bind parameter. And bind parameters don't need "SQL formatting".

Comment: This is one half of the solution; the other half is to use `execute()` instead of `executeQuery()`. Maybe even try-with-resources while at it..